# Handling Dates from Oracle to SQL Server 2005 using OPENQUERY

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle, sql-server-2005, datetime

I have linked SQL Server 2005 to an Oracle Server, and am using OpenQuery() to pass data from Oracle to SQL Server.

So, for instance, the following query works fine:

```
SELECT *
FROM OPENQUERY(ORACLE_LINK, 'SELECT FIELD1
    FROM ORACLE.TABLE1');
```

Everything works, unless I ask for a field which is a date/time in the Oracle database.  For instance, say that TABLE1 has ten fields, one of which is a timestamp.  If I ask for all nine fields except for the timestamp, it works.  If I ask:

```
SELECT *
FROM OPENQUERY(ORACLE_LINK, 'SELECT *
    FROM ORACLE.TABLE1');
```

I get the following error:

```
OLE DB provider "MSDAORA" for linked server "ORACLE_LINK" returned message "Oracle error occurred, but error message could not be retrieved from Oracle.".
OLE DB provider "MSDAORA" for linked server "ORACLE_LINK" returned message "Data type is not supported.".
```

I also get the same error if I ask for only the timestamp field.

What is the best way of handling this error?  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do it with this function (partial code):

```
select @StringOut = '{ts ''''' + convert(varchar(20), @DateIn, 20) + ''''' }';
RETURN @StringOut
```

and this goes into the query:

```
and procedure_date_dt = ' + dbo.TimestampString(@date) + '
and event_type = ''''Time Notation''''
```

and it works when I run it.

Comment: Thanks. Are you able to elaborate on how to use this partial code with the code example in my question?

Comment: Oh, you are having trouble in the select clause.  What happens when you run "select * from openquery (ORACLE_SISI, 'select sysdate from dual');", but with your server name?

Comment: I get the now-time, successfully.

Comment: What is the datatype of the problematic field?

Comment: It is a timestamp.  I've solved the problem by casting the timestamp as a date in the query string.  Thanks for your help!